# bootstrap slider is not sliding

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i want to make a slider using bootstrap carousel but my slider does not slide it doesnt slide even when i click on the button

i tested many other bootstrap sliders and i have the same problem with them,i found many questions in stack overflow but they were all javascript

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="main">
            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <a href="hkh.html">
                    <div class="carousel-item ">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://fortniteinsider.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Fortnite-Chapter-2-Season-1-Loading-Screen-Leaked-2.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                        <div class="slidetoppage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                            <h5>test title 3</h5>
                            <p>test desc</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                            </a>
                    <a href="gh.php">
                    <div class="carousel-item ">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://assets.pcmag.com/media/images/668289-fortnite-chapter-2.jpg?thumb=y&width=1280&height=720" alt="First slide">
                        <div class="slidetoppage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                            <h5>test title 2</h5>
                            <p>test desc</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                            </a>
                    <a href="gooz.php">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://assets.pcmag.com/media/images/668289-fortnite-chapter-2.jpg?thumb=y&width=1280&height=720" alt="Second slide">
                        <div class="slidetoppage">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                            <h5>test title 1</h5>
                            <p>test desc</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                            </a>
                                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you checked your browser's console for errors?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined
    at b.slide (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at b.next (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2) sorry i didn't know i can see error in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include your `js` files. The ones which are shown below;

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here is also the the link of bootstrap that it explains what to do at the very beginning: [Bootstrap Introduction](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/)